# Is there a way to attach a document into an object

Tags: attachment, document

I know I can add an attachment into a record. But the issue is, if there is a document object containing a file and I want my record to be able to connect to that document, is there a way to do this?

There are scenarios where one file is not used by just one record, and we don't want user to upload the files each time. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new object specific for attachments and a junction object to create the relation to your other object(s).

If you disable attachments on your primary object, you'd be sure people wouldn't wrongly use the standard attachments and avoid confusion for your users.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to create a lookup or master-detail relationship to document/attachment. And that's the main reason I am asking. I kind of resolved the issue by using a VF page to pop up the SF id of the document record and store it. Then calculating the url based on the id. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: I meant to create a new custom object on which you enable attachments, not to reference attachments on their own.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I guess that's a proper solution and + 1 for this one. But might not be the best way for our situation though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any possibility of storing files in objects  - my idea would be to upload the file on the server, then attach it by creating URL field in desired object and populating it with file address.

Comment: Besides a server chatter files could also be used in your scenario.